# Uncaught TypeError when trying to call 'loading' with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, loading

I've spent 5 hours just trying to make the loading message show up using jQuery Mobile. Instead, I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'loading'

Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.mobile.loading("show");
</script>
```

Here is the current code:

```
    <head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you're encountering is due to an inaccurate method reference, as stated in the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'loading'

The `loading()` method was added in 1.2, but you're using 1.1.1, which is why it states it does not have a `loading` method.

> Show or hide the page loading message, which is configurable via
>   $.mobile.loader prototype options as described in the widget docs or
>   can be controlled via a params object.

Usage:

```
//cue the page loader
$.mobile.loading( 'show' );

//use theme swatch "b", a custom message, and no spinner
$.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "b", text: "foo", textonly: true });
```

The method that you should be using for your version is `showPageLoadingMsg()`.

Usage:

```
//cue the page loader
$.mobile.loadingMessage = 'Loading...Please wait';
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

//use theme swatch "b", a custom message, and no spinner
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "This is only a test", true);
```

Comment: Where i can found the 1.2 version ?

Comment: It appears as though they have not released version 1.2 yet. http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

Comment: So can i have just a sample work fine with the $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() Please?  because i put it and no loading msg show up and no error apper.

Comment: You have to set the loadingMessage value first.

Answer (score 0):

You use jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js . jQuery mobile 1.1.1 is not supported

```
$.mobile.loading("show");
```

and this method is in jQuery mobile 1.2.0.

It is supported

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

And you can configure loadMessage in *mobileinit* method.

EX:

```
 $.mobile.loadingMessage = "Loading Message"; 
 $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
 $.mobile.loadingMessageTheme="a";
```

I had same issue  and finally i found it.

Answer (score -1):

Finally i found the solution

it's can't be called directly from a simple javascript function, i need to use it with a page

```
$("#Step1").live("pageshow", function () {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();  
});
```